# 404 error when posting to node server (port 8080) from react app (port 3000)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend

I am building my frontend in React (running on localhost:3000) and when the user submits a image upload I want it to send through Node and Express, so triggering this row when the form is submitted (in `App.js`file)
`const result = await axios.post('/images', formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})`

In my `server.js` in a folder named "backend" (listening to port 8080). I am handling that post request using:

```
app.post('/images', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file
  ...
}
```

But when I submit an image through the client I am getting the following error:

`POST http://localhost:3000/images 404 (Not Found)`

Could it be because `server.js` is not listening to `port 3000`? When I change that the client displays nothing.

Comment: Your server listens on port 8080. The correct URL is http://localhost:8080/images

Comment: I see, is there any way to make the app understand that by itself? I am thinking of hosting it in the cloud where the port can be arbitrary, what is the best practice when it comes to specifying the port?

Comment: That's not possible. You have to know the port. It's part of the URL. Your backend can't have a arbitrary, random, changing URL.